# How can I hide Home in my menu in a specific page?

Tags: php, css, html, theme-twenty-eleven, homepage

I want to how can I hide the home in the menu without setting show_home in functions.php to false, I just want to do is hide it in a specific page. How can I do this? I am using the Twenty-Eleven Theme.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress adds a unique class for each page in the body tag, you can use that class to target specific elements on your page through CSS.

```
.page-id-32 .menu-item-31 {display:none;}
```

Comment: general a plausible idea, but unfortunately, it does not do this for the 'home' tab, if the menu is done with the fallback function `wp_page_menu()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable editing the theme, you could add a little PHP to your home link that will apply a CSS class when it's shown on a certain page:

`<?php if (is_page('Page Title')) : echo ' class="current"'; endif; ?>`

Where 'Page Title' is the title of the page on which you want to hide the button, and the class .current is applied when a user is on that page. Then just add the `display: none` CSS to .current.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `'show_home'` to false on that page only:

```
'show_home'   => ! is_page( 'The page title, ID or slug here' )
```